# Android Auto Exposure Lock Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, opencv, nullpointerexception, camera

I am developing an opencv app for android and am trying to lock my camera's auto exposure. I have been following the tutorial 3 sample in OpenCV4Android in order to access the various camera parameters. I have made a custom camera class for accessing the camera properties.

Full error:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters 
android.hardware.Camera.getParameters() on a null object reference
at {PackageName}.MainView.lockAutoExposure()
```

This is my MainView class so far (the custom camera class):

```
public class MainView extends JavaCameraView {

private static final String TAG = "Urop::MainView";

public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void lockAutoExposure() {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setAutoExposureLock(true);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}


}
```

Here is where I instantiate the class and set it up in the main activity:

```
private MainView mOpenCvCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch(status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Loaded Successfully");
            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);
            mOpenCvCameraView.lockAutoExposure();
            System.loadLibrary("opencvnative");


            break;
        }
    ...
```

My permissions in the manifest. Not sure if I need anything else:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Looking at the tutorial 3 sample, I don't see any initialization of mCamera, so I believe it is a member of the parent class.

Comment: Ok.. Try to add mCamera = Camera.open() before getParameters()

Comment: the app no longer crashes, but nothing is being displayed on screen and now i get "error 2" in logcat

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by moving lockAutoExposure to the onCameraViewStarted() method.

Answer (score 0):

`mCamera` is a null object. It is failing because you are trying to call `getParameters()` on something that does not exist (unless you are not showing us the full code?)

Comment: App no longer crashes, but I get "error 2" in logcat